# Getting confidence intervals on prediction from caret::train

Tags: r, r-caret

I'm trying to figure out how to get confidence intervals from a caret::train linear model.

My first try was just to run predict with the usual lm confidence intervals arguments:

```
m <- caret::train(mpg ~ poly(hp,2), data=mtcars, method="lm")
predict(m, newdata=mtcars, interval="confidence", level=0.95)
```

But it looks like the object returned from caret::train doesn't have this implemented.

My second attempt was to extract the finalModel and predict on that:

```
m <- caret::train(mpg ~ poly(hp,2), data=mtcars, method="lm")
fm <- m$finalModel
predict(fm, newdata=mtcars, interval="confidence", level=0.95)
```

But I get the error

```
Error in eval(predvars, data, env) : object 'poly(hp, 2)1' not found
```

Digging deeper it seems that the final model has some weird representation for the formula and is searching for a 'poly(hp, 2)1' column in my newdata rather than evaluating the formula. The m$finalModel looks like this:

```
Call:
lm(formula = .outcome ~ ., data = dat)

Coefficients:
   (Intercept)  `poly(hp, 2)1`  `poly(hp, 2)2`  
         20.09          -26.05           13.15
```

I should add that I'm not just using `lm` because I'm using caret to fit the model through cross validation.

How can I get the confidence intervals from the linear model fit through caret::train?

Comment: What output do you get from `formula(ms$finalModel)`? The output presented is not equivalent to the formula in your first box.

Comment: @Oliver Sorry I had the formula wrong in the question, the output is `.outcome ~ \`poly(hp, 2)1\` + \`poly(hp, 2)2\`
<environment: 0x0000000091b1a6e8>`

Comment: It seems you updated, at which point it is more in line. Which version of `R` and `caret` are you using? Executing `predict(fm, newdata=mtcars, interval="confidence", level=0.95)` correctly gives me the prediction intervals.

Comment: `R version 3.6.0 (2019-04-26)` and `caret_6.0-84`

Comment: It shouldn't be the problem, but try updating `R` to 3.6.1. Hopefuly another kind soul can find a better answer.

Comment: @Oliver updating R and all packages didn't do anything, thanks for your help!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199699/discussion-between-fish11-and-oliver).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Disclaimer:

This is a horrible answer, or maybe the `caret` package just has a horrible implementation of this specific issue. In either case it seems fitting for opening an issue or wish on [their github](https://github.com/topepo/caret/issues) if not already existing (either a wish for more diversified `predict` functions or fixing the naming used in `object$finalModel`)

The problem (which occured on second trial) stems from how the `caret` package internally handles the diverse fitting procedures, basically restricting the predict function for what seems to be cleaning and standardization purposes.

## Problem:

The problem is two-fold.

1. The `predict.train` does not allow for prediction/confidence intervals
2. The `finalModel` contained in the output of `train(...)` contains a formula that is unusually formatted.

The two problems seems to be stem from the formatting of `train` and the usage in `predict.train`. Focusing first on the latter problem, this is apparent by looking at the output from

```
formula(m$finalModel)
#`.outcome ~ `poly(hp, 2)1` + `poly(hp, 2)2`)
```

Obviously some formatting is performed while running `train`, as the expecteed output would be `mpg ~ poly(hp, 2)`, while the output has expanded the RHS (and added quotes/tags) and changed the LHS. As such it would be nice to either fixup the formula, or be able to use the formula.

Looking into how the `caret` package uses this in the `predict.train` function reveals the code piece below for `newdata` input

```
predict.formula
#output
--more code
if (!is.null(newdata)) {
    if (inherits(object, "train.formula")) {
        newdata <- as.data.frame(newdata)
        rn <- row.names(newdata)
        Terms <- delete.response(object$terms)
        m <- model.frame(Terms, newdata, na.action = na.action, 
            xlev = object$xlevels)
        if (!is.null(cl <- attr(Terms, "dataClasses"))) 
            .checkMFClasses(cl, m)
        keep <- match(row.names(m), rn)
        newdata <- model.matrix(Terms, m, contrasts = object$contrasts)
        xint <- match("(Intercept)", colnames(newdata), 
            nomatch = 0)
        if (xint > 0) 
            newdata <- newdata[, -xint, drop = FALSE]
    }
}
--more code
    out <- predictionFunction(method = object$modelInfo, 
                modelFit = object$finalModel, newdata = newdata, 
                preProc = object$preProcess)
```

For the less experienced `R` users, we basically see, that a `model.matrix` is constructed from scratch without using the output of `formula(m$finalModel)` (we can use this!), and later some function is called to predict based on the `m$finalModel`. Looking into `predictionFunction` from the same package reveals that this function simply calls `m$modelInfo$predict(m$finalModel, newdata)` (for our example)

Lastly looking at `m$modelInfo$predict` reveals the below code snippet

```
m$modelInfo$predict
#output
function(modelFit, newdata, submodels = NULL) {
                    if(!is.data.frame(newdata)) 
                        newdata <- as.data.frame(newdata)
                    predict(modelFit, newdata)
                  }
```

Note that `modelFit = m$finalModel` and `newdata` is made with the output above. Also **Note** that the call to `predict` does not allow one to specify `interval = "confidence"`, which is the reason for the first problem.

## Fixing the problem (sorta):

A myriad of ways exist for fixing this problem. One is use `lm(...)` instead of `train(...)`. Another is to utilize the innards of the function to create a data object, that fits the weird model specification, so we can use `predict(m$finalModel, newdata = newdata, interval = "confidence")` in a way that works as expected.

I choose to do the latter.

```
caretNewdata <- caretTrainNewdata(m, mtcars)
preds <- predict(m$finalModel, caretNewdata, interval = "confidence")
head(preds, 3)
#output
                         fit      lwr      upr
Mazda RX4           22.03708 20.74297 23.33119
Mazda RX4 Wag       22.03708 20.74297 23.33119
Datsun 710          24.21108 22.77257 25.64960
```

The function is provided below. for the nerdy, i basically extracted the `model.matrix` building process from `predict.train`, `predictionFunction` and `m$modelInfo$predict`. I will not promise that this function works for the general case usage of every `caret` model, but it is a place to start.

## `caretTrainNewdata` function:

```
caretTrainNewdata <- function(object, newdata, na.action = na.omit){
    if (!is.null(object$modelInfo$library)) 
        for (i in object$modelInfo$library) do.call("requireNamespaceQuietStop", 
                                                    list(package = i))
    if (!is.null(newdata)) {
        if (inherits(object, "train.formula")) {
            newdata <- as.data.frame(newdata)
            rn <- row.names(newdata)
            Terms <- delete.response(object$terms)
            m <- model.frame(Terms, newdata, na.action = na.action, 
                             xlev = object$xlevels)
            if (!is.null(cl <- attr(Terms, "dataClasses"))) 
                .checkMFClasses(cl, m)
            keep <- match(row.names(m), rn)
            newdata <- model.matrix(Terms, m, contrasts = object$contrasts)
            xint <- match("(Intercept)", colnames(newdata), 
                          nomatch = 0)
            if (xint > 0) 
                newdata <- newdata[, -xint, drop = FALSE]
        }
    }
    else if (object$control$method != "oob") {
        if (!is.null(object$trainingData)) {
            if (object$method == "pam") {
                newdata <- object$finalModel$xData
            }
            else {
                newdata <- object$trainingData
                newdata$.outcome <- NULL
                if ("train.formula" %in% class(object) && 
                    any(unlist(lapply(newdata, is.factor)))) {
                    newdata <- model.matrix(~., data = newdata)[, 
                                                                -1]
                    newdata <- as.data.frame(newdata)
                }
            }
        }
        else stop("please specify data via newdata")
    } else
        stop("please specify data data via newdata")
    if ("xNames" %in% names(object$finalModel) & is.null(object$preProcess$method$pca) & 
        is.null(object$preProcess$method$ica)) 
        newdata <- newdata[, colnames(newdata) %in% object$finalModel$xNames, 
                           drop = FALSE]
    if(!is.null(object$preProcess))
       newdata <- predict(preProc, newdata)
    if(!is.data.frame(newdata) && 
      !is.null(object$modelInfo$predict) && 
      any(grepl("as.data.frame", as.character(body(object$modelInfo$predict)))))
           newdata <- as.data.frame(newdata)
    newdata
}
```

Comment: Thank-you so much, it looks like there is an open issue on their Github https://github.com/topepo/caret/issues/187

Comment: Nicely found. I've added a comment to the issue (which seems to not have been resolved since the last discussion in 2015) referencing this answer.

Comment: Good work. I have an issue though. I made a model using train(), method="glmnet". First I got an error saying requireNamespaceQuietStop did not exist but remedied that with caret::"requireNamespaceQuietStop" instead. However, now I get s0-s48 (=number of features) columns with a number for each row in the dataset. Any idea what went wrong?